# How to change the value stored in memory address?

Tags: python, memory

Lets say that memory address `0A7F03E4` stores a value `124`. How to change it to `300` using python? Is there a module supplied for this kind of task?

Comment: You may need to deal with memory protection. If this is code or read only data then you won't be able to write to that address.

Comment: Are you talking about a virtual memory address or a physical memory address?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> memfield = (ctypes.c_char).from_address(0x0A7F03E4)
```

Now you can read memfield, assign to it, do whatever you want. As long as you have access to that memory location, of course.

you can also get a memarray with

```
>>> memarray = (ctypes.c_char*memoryfieldlen).from_address(0x0A7F03E4)
```

which gives you a list of memfields.

Update: I just read that you want to retrieve an integer. in this case, use ctypes.c_int, of course. In general: use the appropriate ctype ;)

Comment: Wouldn't this give you the virtual memory address of the python process rather than the physical address? The latter would probably be inacessible depending on the operating system and process privileges.

Comment: when you want to access a non-data-field, or a field outside of reachable memory, you'll get a segfault, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the built in ctypes module?
It provides a memset function which should give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

On UNIX, you can try to `open()` the `/dev/mem` device to access the physical memory, and then use the `seek()` method of the `file` object set the file pointer to the right location. Then use the `write()` method to change the value. Don't forget to encode the number as a raw string!

Generally, only the `root` user has access to this device, though.